# Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Затем запускался алгоритм оптимизации(,) и строился график поиска решения"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

> Затем запускался алгоритм оптимизации(,) и строился график поиска
>   решения.

"Затем" относится и к первому, и второму предложению, поэтому мне кажется, что запятую ставить не нужно, но я не уверен.

Comment: Не уверен в сочетаемости слов *запускать* и *алгоритм*. В Нацкорпусе для алгоритма нашлись глаголы *реализовать*, *использовать*, *применять*, но не *запускать*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Затем запускался алгоритм оптимизации и строился график поиска решения.**

Вы правы, запятая не нужна, наречие ***затем*** является общим элементом в ССП, так как относится к обоим предложениям. Произношение в одну фразу без обозначения паузы.

**Сравнить:** Затем запускался алгоритм оптимизации,  **и уже с учетом полученных данных** строился график поиска решения.

Здесь у второго предложение собственный  временной показатель "уже с учетом полученных данных", поэтому запятая ставится.