# Какие глаголы сочетаются со словом "алгоритм"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Не уверен в сочетаемости слов *запускать* и *алгоритм* ([Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Затем запускался алгоритм оптимизации(,) и строился график поиска решения"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441650/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8)). В Нацкорпусе для алгоритма нашлись глаголы *реализовать*, *использовать*, *применять*, но не *запускать*.

Answer (score 2):

В значении запуска компьютерного алгоритма это обычное выражение, поскольку оно эквивалентно запуску программы или подпрограммы, реализующей алгоритм. Много примеров находится в "гугл-книгах" поиском по сочетанию "запуск алгоритма".

Пример: А. В. Скворцов, Эффективные алгоритмы вычислительной геометрии

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=g8KlBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0EhT86XA_c2C670lRS5Po2F9yVgA&w=1280

"Сочетающихся" глаголов много: применить, инициализировать (=запустить), предусмотреть, заложить (в программу), выработать, нащупать, отработать, выверить, проверить, испытать, улучшить, усложнить, подобрать...

Answer (score 1):

Как *алгоритм*, так и *оптимизация* — выверенные в своей последовательности программы действий. Запуск алгоритма означает и запуск оптимизации как программы, уже готовой работать.

Очевидно, что какое-то слово из двух — лишнее. И только, думаю, продолжительность и многоступенчатость оптимизации с долей участия оператора может оправдать такое сочетание (*алгоритм оптимизации*), говорящее о вероятном цикле оптимизаций.

Comment: **Оптимизация** — это задача нахождения экстремума целевой функции. Алгоритм, который решает такую задачу, называется **алгоритмом оптимизации**. Известно много **алгоритмов оптимизации**, в Википедии они выделены в отдельную категорию — их там более сотни (основных).

Comment: Оптимизация — это задача... Но есть такая проблема: «Генетические алгоритмы в   з а д а ч е   оптимизации действительных параметров», вывешенная на http://mirznanii.com/a/8821/geneticheskie-algoritmy-v-zadache-optimizatsii-deystvitelnykh-parametrov. Значит ли это, что алгоритм решает задачу задач?

Comment: Ваш случай предполагает такое определение: оптимизация — выбор наилучшего решения в соответствии с заданными критериями. Думаю, оно аккуратнее, но сказанное выше тоже используется (посмотрите Википедию и работы по ссылкам оттуда). Главное было убедить Вас, что понятие "алгоритмы оптимизации" вполне корректно и повсеместно используется. Или посмотрите толковый словарь, там подобное определение слова "оптимизация", но оно не математическое.

Comment: *Понятие "алгоритмы оптимизации" вполне корректно и повсеместно используется* --- Sic!

Comment: Понятие "алгоритмы оптимизации" вполне корректно, когда не схематично, и имеется конкретика определений, например: Генетические алгоритмы для задач комбинаторной оптимизации.